# Tensorflow ran out of memory

Tags: tensorflow

i'm trying to train using ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco.config

and it show this when i try train

> W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:239] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 927.72MiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.

these are the command i ran to train

```
python train.py --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco.config --train_dir=training/ --alsologtostderr
```

Comment: Just Fyi that if i use the ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config this issue would not occur

Comment: What GPU? What does the config say?

Comment: @geometrikal GTX 1080 ti

Answer (score 0):

The answer is get a 16GB memory GPU.